# TSQL Trigger. Two Trigger with same Table

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I have 2 Triggers. Separately, each Trigger works but not together.

Error: Msg 16915, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PrumerAsistence, Line 16
A cursor with the name 'curff' already exists.
The statement has been terminated.

TRIGGER 1:

```
create trigger PrumerAsistence on Hrac FOR UPDATE as
BEGIN
    declare @old DATE
    declare @new date
    declare @YearOld int
    declare @YearNew int
    declare @Year int
    declare @Asistence float

    declare @id int

    declare @as float

    declare curff cursor for (

            select inserted.hid
            from inserted

                         )
    open curff
    fetch from curff into @id
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN 


        set @old = (select min(datum)from prestup where @id = prestup.Hrac_hid)
        set @new = (select max (datum) from prestup where @id = prestup.Hrac_hid)
        set @YearOld = (select Year(@old))
        set @YearNew = (select Year(@new))
        set @Year = @YearNew- @YearOld

        set @as = (
        select sum (Asistence)/ @Year
        from hrac 
        join prestup p on p.hrac_hid = hrac.hid
        where hid = @id )

        update Hrac set Prumer_Asistence = @as where hid = @id 

    fetch from curff into @id 

    END
    close curff
deallocate curff
```

TRIGGER 2:

```
create trigger PrumerGolu on Hrac for UPDATE as
BEGIN
    declare @old DATE
    declare @new date
    declare @YearOld int
    declare @YearNew int
    declare @Year int
    declare @Gol float

    declare @id int

    declare @as float

    declare cur cursor for (

            select inserted.hid
            from inserted

                         )
    open cur 
    fetch from cur into @id
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN 


        set @old = (select min(datum)from prestup where @id = prestup.Hrac_hid)
        set @new = (select max (datum) from prestup where @id = prestup.Hrac_hid)
        set @YearOld = (select Year(@old))
        set @YearNew = (select Year(@new))
        set @Year = @YearNew- @YearOld

        set @gol = (
        select sum (gol)/ @Year
        from hrac 
        join prestup p on p.hrac_hid = hrac.hid
        where hid = @id )

                update Hrac set Prumer_Golu = @gol where hid = @id 

    fetch from cur into @id 

    END
    close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same name for two different table cursor since they are happening at the same time.

**MORE IMPORTANT:**

It is not recommended to use the cursor in your case because of the tuning activity. `@@fetch_status` is a global variable, the scope to it across all the sessions and all batches. It may and it will cause the conflicts and make the result inaccurate.

You'd better to combine these two triggers together to let the SQL executer consider which cursor need to be took care of first, otherwise, may bring the data loss, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare each cursor with the LOCAL option.

Full details on how to do this can be found here, as well as info on how to check what your default setting is (I'm guessing GLOBAL).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189238(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is my project to school and i HAVE TO use 2 trigger. I know why but i have to.

Cant use Local. Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PrumerGolu, Line 38
Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).